# Problema con obtencion de token en Python

Tags: python

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Necesito obtener un token de una API pero me da el siguiente error:

**requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='apiinternos.movistar.com.ar', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /telefonica/sandbox/v1/oauth2/token (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL] dh key too small (_ssl.c:997)')))**

segun el instructivo que me han pasado la forma de acceder es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi codigo es el siguiente:

````
def GetToken(user,secret):
    _headers={
        'accept':'application/json',
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
    payload={
        "grant_type":"client_credentials",
        "client_id":user,
        "client_secret":secret,
        "scope":"scope1"
    }
    
    payload_url= urllib.parse.urlencode(payload)
    resp=requests.post(end_point,headers=_headers,data=payload_url)
    if resp.status_code in range(200,299):
        resp_json=resp.json()
        print(resp_json)
    else:
        print(resp.status_code)
    

GetToken(client_id,secret)```

Alguna idea de por que puede estar fallando?
````

Comment: Te dejo [un link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015537/python-requests-exceptions-sslerror-dh-key-too-small) a una respuesta que le sirvió a muchos en SO, por si te es de utilidad.

Comment: No puedo encontrar esto:  requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.DEFAULT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST += 'HIGH:!DH:!aNULL' probe importando todas las librerias y no sale. Estoy con la version 3.10.1